# Deactivate a portal user in a test class

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Does anybody know how to deactivate a portal user in a **test class**?

I'm trying to delete Accounts with an assoicated Portal User and figured if I deactivated the portal user I may be able to delete the Account.

I've tried updating the User with

```
IsPortalEnabled = false
IsActive = false
```

however this doesn't seem to work. When checking the user after the update, IsPortalEnabled = **true** and IsActive = false. (Is Salesforce seems to be doing something by the scenes?)

Comment: Is this an existing Account or one that was created by the test method explicitly? If it was an existing Account and isn't of interest to the test method your could try using `@IsTest(SeeAllData=false)`

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yes I'd love to isolate my test data like that, however I require @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) so that I can access the standard price book and add Pricebook entries.

I'm trying to delete all Account's (org data) so that I can create 200 Account records to test a single Batch Apex execution.

Comment: Ah, I've been there with the standard price book. It is a real pain. Maybe you could modify the batch apex SOQL to only find the intended testing Accounts? A pain for sure, but it might be easier to filter out the existing records rather than try and delete them all.